# Channels for request-reply pattern using http-outbound-gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I need to send request and receive response synchronously (in the same thread) using http-outbound-gateway in multi-threaded environment (multiple threads doing the same).

I am thinking to use DirectChannel as request and response channels in http-outbound-gateway. If I do that, will the following scenario occurs:

1. thread1 pushed request1 into channel
2. thread1 subscribed for response using subscriber1 with context of request1
3. thread2 pushed resquest2 into channel
4. thread2 subscribed for response using subsciber2 with context of request2
5. response2 received and processed by thread2 using subscriber1 with context of request1

Note: The request/response channels are same for both the threads.

If this occurs how to resolve this problem. My requirement is, always the thread that generated the request should process the corresponding response.

Answer (score 0):

No; it's completely thread safe; thread1 will get its response; thread2 will get its response; there can be no cross-talk.